Examples where different pronunciation changes the meaning of what you’re saying?
The Talmud emphasizes the importance of proper Hebrew pronunciation while leading the community in prayer.

“One may not allow people of Beit She’an, Beit Haifa, or Tivonim to pass before the ark, because they pronounce alef as ayin and ayin as alef.” (Megillah 24b)

Rashi brings down that these people blemish their prayers by confusing these two letters. He brings the example of יאר ה׳ פניו אליך, and how changing יאר to יער changes the meaning of the blessing to that of a curse.

“If they perform Birkat Kohanim, instead of saying יאר ה׳ פניו אליך (May the Lord shine his countenance upon you), they would say יער ה׳ פניו אליך (May the Lord arouse his face toward you), and this is the language of a curse. We see that the word פנים (face) can be conveyed as an expression of anger, as in פני ילכו (Exodus 33), and את פני (Leviticus 20), which Onkelos translates both as “my anger”. Thus, they turn alef into ayin, and blemish their prayers.”

Rashi brings this one example, but are there any others? Other examples don’t have to be alef and ayin, they could be hey and het, khaf and het, tav and tet, and so forth.

לא מאסתים ולא געלתים, if you say גאלתים it's heretical

The Gemara itself cites an example: כשאתה מגיע אצל (ישעיהו ח, יז) וחכיתי לה' לא נמצאת מחרף ומגדף

והללתם את שם ה׳ - וחללתם

הכל כמנהג המקום - Are Sefardic Jews allowed to say Adon-A-i in an Ashkenazi shul where AdonAi is a secular word for "masters" rather than God's name.

Changing letters changes meaning more often than it doesn't. You can see this is any Hebrew text. This isn't even surprising from a linguistic perspective. I don't understand what you are seeking from us.

@AlBerko Sephardic Jews who are knowledgeable in their own tradition, preserve the length difference between פתח and קמץ גדול. An Ashkenazi might not perceive it, but that wouldn’t be the responsibility of the Sephardi.

Ignoring דגש חזק: pronouncing וַיִּקְרָא and וָיִקְרָא, which changes the word to future tense; pronouncing הַגָּדוֹל as הֲגָדוֹל, turning an adjective into a question; pronouncing בַכֹּל as בֲכֹל, removing the definite article.

This is the kind of question that may have many examples. Here are some that I heard of:

Those who do not pronounce ה, instead of אוֹהַב עַמוֹ יִשְׂרָאֵל can easily say אוֹיֵב right in front of Sh'ma.
Those who confuse ח and ה can say חלל for הלל and vice versa.
Those who do not pronounce ע, instead of בּכָל עֵת וּבְכָל שָׁעָה say בּכָל אֵת וּבְכָל שֹׁאָה in Sim Shalom of Shemoneh Esrei
Ashkenazis pronunciation turns לְתַקֵּן עוֹלָם into לְסַכֵּן in the 2nd paragraph of Aleinu.
Those who do not distinguish צ and ס can mispronounce צֶדֶק and סֶדֶק
Due to the fact that voiced consonants next to voiceless ones become voiceless, and the voiceless consonants next to voiced ones get voiced (a phenomenon in some Slavic languages), Mishnah Berurah in the laws of Kaddish asks to be careful in saying יִתְגַּדַּל as many people say יִתְכַּדַּל (like a poor).
Same rule regarding לְמַעַן תִּזְכְּרוּ instead of תִּשְׂכְּרוּ (profit) in the 3rd paragraph of Sh'ma

Perhaps, someone could write a computer program for words in the Siddur and Tanach and identify all cases that people are likely mispronounce based on the rules suggested by OP and the one given here. In addition, it will be good to have a feature to identify tricky words with omitted consonants or mispronounced vowels as suggested by @Chani in the comments (there are many more).

מי כמוך בַּל גבורות - extremely common (although that's omission, not mispronunciation)

In this coming week’s parashah ותרעינה sounds like ותראינה from those who don’t pronounce ע

@J.W.Tanner There are many such tricky words in Chumash. There is a list of them tracked by Eliyahu Levin. magiker72 gave me a contact of him https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/eliyahule/CAMRm8DpqXQ6TGP_RHpF561EFBEjSe-34dWYkLxHiqRR0tgrjGw%40mail.gmail.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

A similar example is גם הצאן והבקר אל ירעו vs. יראו.  And בנו means they built מלרע and in us מלעיל (also as Rashi points out באה changes tense depending where it’s accented)

One of the most common mispronunciation is in the 4th ברכה of ברכת המזון where they say Boreinu = our pit, instead of Bore'einu = our Creator.
The above example of לתקן עולם, also applies in אמת ויציב where it says ומתוקן

An addition to previous answers, a bit funny but true example is, שיר השירים which is supposed to be pronounced as Shir HaShirim which literally means song of songs, one can mispronounce it as Sir haSirim which means, pot of pots. I saw this originally in the halakha ubeagada of Rabbi Shalom Naki
also, כל השונה הלכות meaning all who says at halachot will have a place in olam haba, is to be pronounced Shone and not sone, which means hate, "All who hate halachot will have a place in olam haba", very strange.

I wonder if כקול הסירים תחת הסיר is a joke reference to this.  He wrote kohelet later in his life.

Not a joke, but a common phenomenon of mixing s and sh sounds among the Lithuanian Jews.
